# Check if there are consecutive points in Java list greater than a threshold

Tags: java, list

I have a list `List<Double>` representing latency values collected from server metrics. I want to check if there are 3 consecutive values are greater than a given threshold.

e.g. threshold = 20

list 1: `[15.121, 15.245, 20.883, 20.993, 15.378, 15.447, 15.839, 15.023]` should return false because there are only two values `20.883, 20.993` that are greater than 20.

list 2: `[15.121, 15.245, 20.883, 20.993, 15.378, 15.447, 20.193, 15.023]` should return false because there are only three values greater than 20 but they are not consecutive.

list 3: `[15.121, 15.245, 20.883, 20.993, 20.193, 15.378, 15.447, 15.023]` should return true because there are three consecutive values `20.883, 20.993, 20.193` greater than 20.

I could do a loop with index to check on list.get(i-1), list.get(i), and list.get(i+1).

```
public boolean isAboveThreshold(List<Double> list, Double threshold) {
    // CONSECUTIVE_NUMBER = 3
    if (list.size() < CONSECUTIVE_NUMBER) {
        return false;
    }

    return !IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 2)
        .filter(i -> list.get(i) > threshold && list.get(i + 1) > threshold && list.get(i + 2) > thread)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .isEmpty();
}
```

Just wondering is there a more efficient way to do it?

---

Updated with `anyMatch` base on [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner)'s comment.

```
public boolean isAboveThreshold(List<Double> values, Double threshold, int consecutiveNumber) {
    if (values.size() < consecutiveNumber) {
        return false;
    }

    return IntStream
        .range(0, values.size() - consecutiveNumber + 1)
        .anyMatch(index -> 
            IntStream.range(index, index + consecutiveNumber)
                .allMatch(i -> values.get(i) > threshold)
        );
}
```

Comment: You can't sort the data or you lose "consecutive-ness", so I don't think there's anything faster than simply iterating through the list, which is already only O(n).  Do you have the option to check the last two values when storing a new one?

Comment: The list is retrieved from an API call so I don't add new items on the fly.

May be I can sort the list and map the result in tuple with value and index? Then I may just need to work on a smaller subset to find if there's consecutive index.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use `IntStream.range(...).anyMatch(i -> ...)`, rather than `!IntStream.range(...).filter(i -> ...).collect(toList()).isEmpty()`, because the former can stop as soon as it finds a match, whereas the latter scans the whole list, builds a list, and then just checks if that list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest just to do it with an enhanced for loop, keeping a count of the number of elements you have seen in a contiguous run:

```
int count = 0;
for (double d : list) {
  if (d >= threshold) {
    // Increment the counter, value was big enough.
    ++count;
    if (count >= 3) {
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    // Reset the counter, value too small.
    count = 0;
  }
}
return false;
```